# How do I zip & download files on an ubuntu server?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, compression

I have gotten SSH access into an EC2 instance of Ubuntu.

I want to zip an entire folder, and download it to my local machine.

The folder is large - 2GB+.

How do I do that?

Comment: What's with the downvote?

Comment: Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The are several ways to do what you want, one of them, assuming your local machine is a Windows one, would be:

1. Acces via putty onto the ubuntu machine
2. use tar to archive and compress the directory, for example using `bzip2`

   ```
   tar cjvf /path/to/target/archive.tar.bz2 /path/to/directory/to/compress
   ```
3. use psftp, access to the ubuntu machine and download the tar file

Read the `tar(1)` manual page for more details.